# Regular expression beginning and ending with parentheses

Tags: python, regex

Here is a pattern object that I tried to make in python using the re module. What I am going for is something that will take the string "(\exists x)(Px*Qx)" and find just the "Px*Qx" portion. I thought that I would try to use the lookahead and lookbehind assertions. I'm not sure if I am using this wrong or if there is something wrong with the ( character.

```
p = re.compile(r'?<=[(]\w+?=[)]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: You should use a parser for this...

Comment: Did you try just looking for `[^()]+`, to get things that aren’t parens?

Comment: this will never work for nested parens (..ie `((1))`) just because of how regex works ...... but tchrist's suggestion (`'\([^()]*\)'`)should work fine for non nested parens

Comment: What is the common pattern about input string `(\exists x)(Px*Qx)`? Do you want to ensure something like `(\word word)(TARGET)` or just want to obtain the string inside second parantheses?

Comment: Thanks for the advise carrot-top. I will be trying the pyparsing module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problems

1. You need to put tokens into a group to apply lookbehind (**add parentheses around**): `(?<=[(]\w+(?=[)]))`
2. Python **doesn't support** variable repetition inside lookbehind. So, you can not write `\w+` there.
3. A regex with only a lookbehind **matches nothing**! Lookbehind means *"Try to match this thing, then stay at the same starting position to match following part of the regex."* But, in your case, no following part. So, nothing matches.

### Solution

If you want to obtain text inside the last parentheses:

```
^.*\((.*?)\)$
```

If you want to skip first parentheses and obtain remaining part removing parentheses:

```
^\(.*?\)\((.*)\)$
```

Please define what you want more concretely, so I can help you to write a proper regex.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. What I want to do is obtain the text inside the last parentheses.